# Making offer gives error: TypeError: opts.selling.toXDRObject is not a function

Tags: manageofferoperation, offer, ico

I was trying to make **buy offer** for a  newly created asset (MCoin).

I am getting error:

> TypeError: opts.selling.toXDRObject is not a function

The code of node script goes by:

```
server.loadAccount(distributor.publicKey)
    .then(function(account){
        var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account)
                .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.manageOffer({
                    selling: 'MCoin',
                    buying: 'XLM',
                    amount : 200,
                    price: 2,
                    offerId: 0,
                }))
                .build();
        transaction.sign(distributorKeyPair);
        //console.log(transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR('base64'));

        server.submitTransaction(transaction)
            .then(function(transactionResult){
                //console.log(JSOn.stringify(transactionResult));
                console.log('\n Success!')
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log('An error has occured');
                console.log(err);
            })

    })
    .catch(function(e){
        console.log(e);
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I was not representing the Assets that I need to sell properly.

> Replacing `MCoin` with `new StellarSdk.Asset('MCoin',
>   'GCKRPJXPGNHBPMRCXEX4MDH532BN5RLUJJOMVACA3CB7E2LWSTKTB5U2')` solved
>   the problem.

Ideally, an asset is Stellar is represented by its code and the issuer account Id.

Final code becomes:

```
server.loadAccount(distributor.publicKey)
    .then(function(account){
        var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account)
                .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.manageOffer({
                    selling: new StellarSdk.Asset('MCoin', 'GCKRPJXPGNHBPMRCXEX4MDH532BN5RLUJJOMVACA3CB7E2LWSTKTB5U2'),
                    buying:  StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
                    amount : '200',
                    price: 2,
                    offerId: 0,
                }))
                .build();
        transaction.sign(distributorKeyPair);
        //console.log(transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR('base64'));

        server.submitTransaction(transaction)
            .then(function(transactionResult){
                //console.log(JSOn.stringify(transactionResult));
                console.log('\n Success!')
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log('An error has occured');
                console.log(err);
            })

    })
    .catch(function(e){
        console.log(e);
    })
```

Also note that **amount** must be string.